# POSIX sh check (test) value of builtin set option

Tags: sh, posix

In POSIX sh you may set options with set:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -u;

echo "$notset";
```

that gives expected:

> parameter not set or null

but how to check if option `-e` is set or not?

I want at some point of my script to turn it off but set it back to on only if it was previously on.

Comment: Note: all semicolons in your snippet are extraneous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell options are held in `$-` as a string of single characters. You test for `-e` with

```
case $- in
(*e*)    printf 'set -e is in effect\n';;
(*)      printf 'set -e is not in effect\n';;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the accepted answer I did this:

to store option state (empty string = off, option char = on)

```
option="e"
option_set="$(echo $- | grep "$option")"
```

to restore it to previous value stored in `option_set` in case I modified its state:

```
if [ -n "$option_set" ]; then 
    set -"$option"
else 
    set +"$option" 
fi
```

here's a test script if you'd like to play with that solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

return_non_zero() {
    echo "returing non zero"
    return 1
}

set -e # turn on option
# set +e # turn off option

echo "1. options that are set: $-"

option="e"
option_set="$(echo $- | grep "$option")"

echo "turn off "$option" option" && set +"$option"
# echo "turn on "$option" option" && set -"$option"

echo "2. options that are set: $-"

# should terminate script if option e is set
return_non_zero

# restore option to prev value
if [ -n "$option_set" ]; then 
    set -"$option"
else 
    set +"$option" 
fi

echo "3. options that are set: $-"

echo "END"
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Before sourcing any other script (if required), add the following line
if [ -z ${-%*e*} ]; then PARENT_ERREXIT=true; else PARENT_ERREXIT=false; fi

. source-any-other-script-if-required.sh

...

# Turn the errexit off whenever you wish
set +e

...

# Set back the option the way it was when entering your script
if [ $PARENT_ERREXIT = "true" ]; then set -e; else set +e; fi

...
```

This feature is called Parameter Expansions.
Any of the following four Remove Pattern operator can be used for the Parameter Expansions.
`${parameter%[word]}`
`${parameter%%[word]}`
`${parameter#[word]}`
`${parameter##[word]}`

Read more from the [Official Documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Also, anyone looking for Bash specific, you can use the following -
`if [[ -o errexit ]]; then PARENT_ERREXIT=true; else PARENT_ERREXIT=false; fi`

This feature is called Bash Conditional Expressions.
Read more from the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html).